# ES6 Computed (dynamic) property names

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am reading [this](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals) explanation in order to get a better understanding of ES6.

In the bit about Enhanced Object Literals, this is given as example code:

```
var obj = {
    ... (removed as not relevant) ...

    // Computed (dynamic) property names
    [ 'prop_' + (() => 42)() ]: 42
};
```

I understand what is happening except for the last sentence

I get that

```
: 42
```

Is the value (Number) that will be given to the property, and that

```
[ 'prop_' + ... ]
```

Is a dynamic variable name that starts with the string **prop_**.

However, what does this mean/do?

```
(() => 42)()
```

Comment: It's basically an IIFE, something like `(function() { return 42 }())`

Comment: As for the duplicate, I feel it's not a duplicate, as my question is not what the => specfically means, but the entire sentence, including the usage of the ()'s.

Comment: And thanks @adeneo, your comment makes me understand better what happens here.

Comment: @Mortaza The mere addition of the `()` to execute the function does not make the question unique, I'd say; it's still a dump in my mind.

Answer (score 3):

`(() => 42)()` is a long way of writing `42` in ES6 using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).